# AWS - Cannot read "domainName" of undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

[EDIT]
I am new to AWS and I've been trying to make a real-time chat application. I saw this code, so I might as well try this. I tried to follow everything but it seems there is a problem.
[END]

I got an error with this code stating, **Cannot read "domainName" of undefined** which got me confused. Is this because of my API Gateway? I already connected this to another route named "Message" and I already have the integration request of my connect and disconnect.
Below is my code:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});
require('./index.js');

let send = undefined;
function init(event) {  
    console.log(event);
    const apigwManagementApi = new AWS.ApiGatewayManagementApi({    
        apiVersion: '2018-11-29',    
        endpoint: event.requestContext.domainName + '/' + event.requestContext.stage
    });      
    
        send = async (connectionId, data) => {  
            await apigwManagementApi.postToConnection({ 
                ConnectionId: connectionId, 
                Data: `Echo: ${data}` }).promise();  
        }}
    
exports.handler =  (event, context, callback) => {
    init(event);  
    let message = JSON.parse(event.body).message;
    getConnections().then((data) => {        
        console.log(data.Items);
        callback(null, {
            statusCode: 200,
            
        });
        data.Items.forEach(function(connection) {           
            console.log("Connection " +connection.connection_id);         
            send(connection.connection_id, message);        
            
        });    
        
    });        
    return {};
    
};
    
function getConnections(){
 const params = {
        TableName: 'GroupChat',
    }
    return db.scan(params).promise();
}
```

Comment: What is being printed by `console.log(event);`?

Comment: Hello. It's this one `{ action: 'onMessage', message: 'Hello Everyone' }`

Comment: So if there is no property called `requestContext` in that event object you are printing, how do you expect the code to handle this event?

Comment: I have no idea where did the event get that message. Tried looking for it but can't find it. I'm very very new to aws and I'm following an instructions in a website.

Comment: How was the Lambda function invoked? Via API Gateway? Did you run a test directly in the AWS Lambda console?

Comment: Yes via API Gateway and I also run a test directly in AWS Lambda console.

Comment: At some point when you invoked the Lambda function in your testing you passed that message to the Lambda function. Check what test events you are using.

Comment: Oh right. I completely forgot about that. Yes, that's what I did put in the test hahaha how about the domainName problem? Is this because of the API Gateway?

Comment: I don't think you understand, your Lambda function is expecting an event object that looks like `{requestContext: {domainName: "whatever"}}` and you called it with some other test event that didn't match that format. That is your entire issue right now, you aren't using a test event that matches what your Lambda function expects.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for pointing it out. This is also the same as my last project. Where I need to connect the lambda and the test event should have 
`{"requestContext": {"connectionId": "garbage"}}` Thank you so much!

Comment: I assume once you call it from API Gateway the event will have that? It depends on how you have the API Gateway integration with Lambda configured.